# Excel function about Date

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

i want to know the function to get .01.09.2016 from 1/9/2016 in excel.I applied this function "=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,4,20),RIGHT(A1,2))" but this gives result 17.08.4243 from 09/01/2016 and also customized these two cells as dd/mm/yyyy and dd.mm.yyyy.

Comment: Excel stores dates as a number of days since 1/1/1900 - the date 9th January 2016 is 42378 days after January 1st 1900.  So, splitting the number 42378 as you have gives the year 4237, month number 78 (which Excel calculates as a about 6.5 years - giving year 4243), the day number is also 78 - no idea how many months gets added here.  Just reformat the number as @user3240704 has suggested (it will be treated as text) or give it a custom number format of `mm.dd.yyyy` (it will still be treated as a date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the TEXT function

```
    =TEXT(A1,"dd.mm.yyyy")
```

Comment: thnx.It was really helpful

Comment: If it answered your question please mark as answered

Comment: thnx for ur suggestion